# ZK drag and drop problem

Tags: drag-and-drop, listbox, zk

I can not get new ordered model list from listbox after making drag & drop operation. On view I can see that it is ordered but when I try to get  new list of items it returns me original list. is there any way to get listmodel as ordered on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved  it making manual sort in model list. I realized that when using drag and drop it only visually changing  list items orders. here my working code

```
<listbox id="listBox_Action"
                                        fixedLayout="true" width="300px"
                                        model="@{mainCtrl.comboModelAction}"
                                        selectedItem="@{mainCtrl.selectedAction}" mold="paging"
                                        pageSize="25" forward="onSelect=onSelectedPanelChange()"
                                        onSelect="bd.value=self.selectedItem.label;bd.close();">


                                        <listhead>
                                            <listheader
                                                label="${c:l('SYSADM.SelectAction.combo.ActionName')}" />

                                        </listhead>
                                        <listitem
                                            self="@{each=ACTION_LIST}">
                                            <listcell
                                                label="@{ACTION_LIST.action_func}"
                                                value="@{ACTION_LIST.action_func}" />

                                        </listitem>
                                    </listbox>
```

And here java class

```
public void onChangeList(ForwardEvent event) {
        DropEvent dropEvent = (DropEvent) event.getOrigin();

        // Listitem li = (Listitem)event.getTarget();
        // Listbox lb =(Listbox)event.getOrigin().getTarget();

        int indexOfdraggedListitem =0;
        int indexOfdroppedListitem =0;

        Listitem draggedListitem = (Listitem) dropEvent.getDragged();

        if (dropEvent.getTarget() instanceof Listitem) {

            droppedListitem = (Listitem) dropEvent.getTarget();

            indexOfdraggedListitem = left.getIndexOfItem(draggedListitem);

            indexOfdroppedListitem = left.getIndexOfItem(droppedListitem);

            if (indexOfdraggedListitem > indexOfdroppedListitem) {
                droppedListitem.getParent().insertBefore(draggedListitem, droppedListitem);

                draggableListLeft.add(indexOfdroppedListitem, draggableListLeft.get(indexOfdraggedListitem));

                // Collections.swap(draggableListLeft, indexOfdraggedListitem,
                // indexOfdroppedListitem);

                draggableListLeft.remove(indexOfdraggedListitem + 1);
                // draggableListLeft.add(indexOfdroppedListitem + 1,
                // temp_Fie_Dif_Request_Set);

            } else {

                droppedListitem.getParent().insertBefore(draggedListitem, droppedListitem);

                draggableListLeft.add(indexOfdroppedListitem, draggableListLeft.get(indexOfdraggedListitem));

                draggableListLeft.remove(indexOfdraggedListitem);

            }

        } else   {
            indexOfdraggedListitem = left.getIndexOfItem(draggedListitem);
            left.appendChild(draggedListitem);
            draggableListLeft.add(draggableListLeft.get(indexOfdraggedListitem));
            draggableListLeft.remove(indexOfdraggedListitem);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you'd better to maintain the order in the model, rather than the component set. In other words, you should change the order in the model when drag and drop affected.